# calling numpy in python 3.4.0

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x

So i was trying to use the updated version of python to work on some code since the older version was limiting me in some ways so i got the python 3. I was using python 2.7.6 before which came pre-installed with ubuntu. While i was trying to call numpy using the command

`import numpy as np`

i keep getting an error message that says there is no module named numpy. Is there a different command that i need to use to be able to use numpy in python 3.4.0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*so this question has more negatives on it compared to the other questions that i posted and this has caused for there to be a question ban on me. Is there any way that i could improve this question and resubmit it for consideration?*

Comment: Did you install numpy?  Different versions of Python won't share packages, so if you installed Python 3.4 you'll have to install numpy for that (as well as any other libraries you want to use).

Comment: so this question has more negatives on it compared to the other questions that i posted and this has caused for there to be a question ban on me. Is there any way that i could improve this question and resubmit it for consideration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=numpy&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all) port of numpy with:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
```

Comment: Now you can import numpy with Python 3!

Comment: Let me know if it doesn't work. Otherwise feel free to mark as answer.

Comment: so for some reason this is my most negative voted question and has led me to being on a question hold. Any ideas, how i could get out of that

Comment: @sanster9292 You are being downvoted because you asked an obvious question. You can still give me my correct answer back. People here are so strict about SO policy they can't really understand a valid question.